# Obtaining the value of only one ancestor node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML that looks like this.  It is externally supplied and cannot be changed:

```
<locations>
  <country iso_code="CA">
    <name>Canada</name>
    <state abbreviation="AB">
      <name>Alberta</name>
      <city>
        <name>Leduc</name>
        <location id="1"/>
      </city>
    </state>
    <state abbreviation="BC">
      <name>British Columbia</name>
      <city>
        <name>Abbotsford</name>
        <location id="2"/>
        <location id="3"/>
      </city>
    </state>
    </country>
  <country iso_code="US">
    <name>United States</name>
    <state abbreviation="AZ">
      <name>Arizona</name>
      <city>
        <name >Wikiup</name>
        <location id="1"/>
      </city>
    </state>
  </country>
</locations>
```

My XSL looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//location[@id]">
      <xsl:call-template name="location"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="location">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>,
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::city[1]"/>,
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::state[1]"/>,
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::state[1]/@abbreviation"/>,
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::country[1]"/>,
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::country[1]/@iso_code"/>,
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run xsltproc, I get this output (I took out the extra lines to make it samller):

```
1,Leduc,AlbertaLeduc,AB,CanadaAlbertaLeducBritish ColumbiaAbbotsford,CA,
2,Abbotsford,British ColumbiaAbbotsford,BC,CanadaAlbertaLeducBritish ColumbiaAbbotsford,CA,
3,Abbotsford,British ColumbiaAbbotsford,BC,CanadaAlbertaLeducBritish ColumbiaAbbotsford,CA,
...etc...
```

The problem is when I do the ancestor[1]:: it pulls up the values of all the ancesotors, not the just the one I'm looking for.

Here is what the output should look like:

```
1,Leduc,Alberta,AB,Canada,CA,
2,Abbotsford,British Columbia,BC,Canada,CA,
3,Abbotsford,British Columbia,BC,Canada,CA,
...etc...
```

I tried using ../../. notation and got the same result.  I played with a few other notations and it either doesn't work, or I end up with these concatenated values again.

How do I get that value of only the immediate parent to the node I'm processing, not all of them at that level?

Hopefully I'm using the correct terminology here. This is my first use of XSL for a one off project.

The web guys in the shop are stumped as well. They don't use XSL very often.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of XML as boxes, `<value-of>` unpacks the selected box and all boxes it finds inside, throws them away and leaves you with the actual content that was in the boxes.  These are the text nodes.  Attributes are thrown away as well, they are sort of labels glued onto the box.

In the case of `<value-of select="ancestor::state">`, it unpacks the `<state>` box and finds two boxes inside, a `<name>` box and a `<city>` box.  Because you're using `<strip-space elements="*">` it also throws away all the white-space "bubble-wrap", which it would keep otherwise.  It continues to unbox and finds "Alberta" in the `<name>` box, and two more boxes in the `<city>` box:  A `<name>` and a `<location>` box.

And so the game continues: Inside the just unboxed `<name>` box, it finds `Leduc` and keeps that right beside `Alberta`, but it does not find anything in the `<location>` box.  Now, there's nothing more to unpack.  So we're left with a pile of cardboard and bubble wrap waste, and the actual content, which is `Alberta` and `Leduc` (glued together as `AlbertaLeduc`).

Here is a suggested improvement of your code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//location[@id]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="location">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>,
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::city[1]/name"/>,
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::state[1]/name"/>,
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::state[1]/@abbreviation"/>,
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::country[1]/name"/>,
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::country[1]/@iso_code"/>,
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks loads!  I had done the same code as your fix, ie: w/o the template but that was just one of my thrashings around prior to posting the code I had at that time.  Like I said, this is a one off and I don't use xsl ever.  The missing piece for me was /name to get to the value of the node!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you! If this answers your question, could you accept it by clicking the check mark?